# android ошибка JavaMailAPI

Tags: java, android, email, javamail

Подскажите, столкнулся с проблемой, особенность в том, что все работает корректно почта отправляется на устройствах Android 7 и ниже, но как только запускаю на 9, 10 android, мне в логах вылетает ошибка.

Логи с ошибкой:

```
    W/System.err: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:319)
    W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
    at xyz.devdiscovery.supportclient.JavaMailAPI.doInBackground(JavaMailAPI.java:104)
    at xyz.devdiscovery.supportclient.JavaMailAPI.doInBackground(JavaMailAPI.java:16)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1187)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
```

Код активности:

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class JavaMailAPI extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    
    private Context mContext;
    private Session mSession;

    private String mEmail;
    private String mSubject;
    private String mMessage;

    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    public JavaMailAPI(Context mContext, String mEmail, String mSubject, String mMessage) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mEmail = mEmail;
        this.mSubject = mSubject;
        this.mMessage = mMessage;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext,"Отправка сообщения", "Пожалуйста подождите...",false,false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        
        Toast.makeText(mContext,"Сообщение отправлено",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465"); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");



        mSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    //Authenticating the password
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(Utils.EMAIL, Utils.PASSWORD);
                    }
                });

        try {
            
            MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage(mSession);

            
            mm.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Utils.EMAIL));            
            mm.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(mEmail));            
            mm.setSubject(mSubject);           
            mm.setText(mMessage);
            Transport.send(mm);



        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Согласно [FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#getdefaultinstance):

Попробуйте заменить

```
Session.getDefaultInstance()
```

на

```
Session.getInstance()
```

Comment: Не, тоже самое, ошибка так и осталась

Answer (score 1):

Все, вопрос закрыт, не правильно были настроены конфиги SMTP

```
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```